# Share component in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm working on an Angular app that features a map (Google Map API). I'd like to be able to just move the map around (to find locations), add markers, edit existing markers etc. I figured the best course of action would be to give each of these actions their own child route, e.g.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
   ...
   { 
      path: 'location', 
      component: LocationComponent,
      children: [
         { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
         { path: 'overview', component: LocationOverviewComponent },
         { path: 'add', component: AddLocationComponent },
      ]
   },
   ...
}
```

So each component for a child route will need access to the map component, with different behavior:

- There's a '+' FAB in `overview`, but not in `add`
- Clicking the map in `add` will add a marker, but not in `overview`
- ...you get my drift

The trouble is, either component will create their own instance of their map, which is costly, introduces flicker etc.

My question then is, is there a way to maybe initialize the map in the parent route's component and pass it on to the child routes? Or is this approach bound to topple over anyway?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the problem, but if you are adding content to the LocationComponent, you could structure the html with `*ngIf="childRoute=='add'" ` and add the extra Dom to the current component instead of replacing it with a new component.

Answer (score 2):

> My question then is, is there a way to maybe initialize the map in the
>   parent route's component and pass it on to the child routes?

1.**Force initialization**

**Parent.component.template:**

```
<router-outlet></<router-outlet>>
<map></map> // which costly to initialize
```

In the `router-outlet` of parent, child components will come.
Your router will be like:

```
/parent/child1 
/parent/child2
```

With `DI` mechanism it's possible to `inject` any parent component to child

**Chidl1/Child2 class:**

```
class SomeChildComponent{
  constructor(public map: MapComponent){

  }
}
```

2.**With control**. You can use multiple router outlets on parent template:

```
  // where child will come
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> 

    // child can fill this outlet with map. Parent also can fill it
    <router-outlet name="map"></router-outlet>
```

[CODE EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nl52pd). Here, when Crisis center navigated `popup` component opened and stay on the view even navigating to another route like `Heroes`

**some-routing.module.ts:**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'map-route',
    component: MapComponent,
    outlet: 'map'
  },
  {
    path: 'parent-path',
    component: ParentComponent
    children: [
        {
           path: 'child1',
           component: Child1Component               
        },
        {
           path: 'child2',
           component: Child1Component               
        },
    ]

  },
   ...
];
```

Child1.component.ts:

```
export class Child1Component { 

  constructor(public router: Router){
       this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { map: 'map-route' }}]);
  }
}
```

With multiple `route-outlet`s you can control the map component easily(Add/remove from html) from any child component :

```
 // to show it
 this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { map: 'map-route' }}]);

// to destroy it
 this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { map: null }}]);
```

Comment: This sounds like a plan, voting up and checking after lunch.

Comment: Thanks Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

Create some parent route and a some mapcomponent. In the parentcomponent you'll display the mapcomponent and have your routeroutlet which contains your child routes. Something like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <map-component></map-component>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In this routeroutlet you can show the components with their associated actions (e.g. add, remove)

Now we create a service which is injected to the mapcomponent and to the actioncomponents. This service will hold the state.

```
export class MapStateService(){
    action: IAction;

    markers: Markers[] = [];
    otherData: OtherData[] = [];
}
```

Now we create a action interface which will be implemented by our action components:

```
interface IAction {
    clickLocation(x: number, y: number);
    otherAction();
}
```

In the contructor of our actioncomponent inject the stateService and set te current component as action.

```
export class ActionAddComponent extends IAction implements OnInit{
    constructor(private mapStateService: MapStateService)

    ngOnInit(){
        this.mapStateService.action = this;
    }

    clickLocation(x: number, y: number){
        //Do whatever you want, probably add a marker or so.
        this.mapStateService.markers.push(new Marker(x, y));
    }

    otherAction(){

    }
}
```

Now whenever some action is done in your mapcomponent call the method from the action interface:

```
export class MapComponent{
    constructor(private mapStateService: MapStateService)

    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    onMousedown(event) {
        if(!isNullOrUndefined(this.mapStateService.action){
            this.mapStateService.action.clickLocation(event.x, event.y);
        }
    }
}
```